# Double ampersand (&&) as shorthand for if (only) statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator, shorthand, double-ampersand

Is it good to use && as shorthand for if only statement in PHP? I like its simplicity but is it a good practise to use it?

Example: `$a == "foo" && $b = "bar" ;`

Is it more like `if($a == "foo" && $b = "bar"){}` than `if($a == "foo"){ $b = "bar" }` ?
If so, could it cause any problems?

Comment: Is that `=` intentional, or should it be a `==`?

Comment: Intentional to chang $b

Comment: I think KIKO hits the core of the problem here. I assume you try to assign a value to `$b`, but it is confusing. It's very easy to either miss the absence of the second `=` or to assume that it is an error and should be `==`. Code should be as easy to read as possible. In the end it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The term for what you describe is called **branchless condition**. That is not best practice, because of it's bad readability.

But there are some cases where it is very practical and good readable like

```
$logger && $logger->Log('Log my message');
```

which will call `$logger->Log('Log my message')` only if `$logger` is truthy like

```
if ($logger) {
    $logger->Log('Log my message');
}
```

Comment: You could also write: `if ($logger) Log('Log my message');`, which is almost as short.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You could, if no PSR-x coding style guide forces you to use brackets. :)